# Update my pod causes error in GoogleDataTransport Umbrella header

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I've just updated my pod using "pod update" command and I use Firebase pod .
I added new pod and when I compiled my project after that several errors appeared like this:

```
- Umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTEventDataObject.h'
- Umbrella header for module 'GoogleDataTransport' does not include header 'GDTClock.h'
...
...
```

I - use swift5 
  - Xcode 11.0 
  - macOS 10.15

Comment: try "sudo gem install cocoapods" command in terminal. if it not work try "sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods"

Comment: the error not in pod .. it came after I updated my pods including firebase

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
pod deintegrate
pod update
```

The `GoogleDataTransport` references are lingering from old pod versions

Comment: I'm a novice, but this suggestion worked for me:  ```flutter clean``` then ```flutter run```

Comment: God bless you! 

Answer (score 69):

Adding onto Paul's answer: I also had to clear my Pod cache.

```sh
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
pod deintegrate
pod update
```

If you are using Flutter, you probably want to do the flutter clean too.

```sh
flutter clean
```

Comment: with flutter, the flutter clean was necessary, otherwise had the same error even after running previous commands

Comment: just `$ flutter clean` helped me when add in `Podfile` firebase analytics, crashanalytics

Answer (score 18):

This works for me

```
# clear cached artifacts/dependencies
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
rm -rf clone/ios/Pods/
pod cache clean --all

# clear flutter - skip the next 3 lines if you're not using flutter
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios

# run pod install
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Flutter, Firebase and Notification Service target

```
def firebase_core_sdk_version
  if defined?($FirebaseSDKVersion)
    return $FirebaseSDKVersion
  else
    firebase_core_script = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'firebase_core/ios/firebase_sdk_version.rb')
    if File.exist?(firebase_core_script)
      require firebase_core_script
      return firebase_sdk_version!
    end
  end
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', firebase_core_sdk_version
end

target 'NotificationService' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Firebase/Core', firebase_core_sdk_version
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', firebase_core_sdk_version
  # pod 'Firebase/Performance', firebase_core_sdk_version - not working with new version of Performance for NotificationService target.
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', firebase_core_sdk_version 
end
```