# Trying to build my project but it always show error with my grbd_config.h

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, double-quotes, grdb

it show [double-quoted include "grdb_config.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XU6m.png)

but after I changed to angle bracketed,it says [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAFnB.png)
, I have no idea what should I do right now.

(and I try this already:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqKob.png))

build successfuly
Not showing error

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve by following the suggestion in the following link:

[Update my pod causes error in GoogleDataTransport Umbrella header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540898/update-my-pod-causes-error-in-googledatatransport-umbrella-header)

Basically clean up and reinstall the pods again.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
pod deintegrate <project_name>
pod update
```